# How to use result table to make another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following code:

```
SELECT CD_NO, COUNT(purchasedate) AS most_sales
FROM Artist
GROUP BY CD_NO
```

This returns me the amount of sales for each CD, as there is an entry of purchasedate for every sale of CD. However i wish from this to find out which date had the most sales for each CD_NO, and instead of showing a number to showing the date of the most_sales on that day. So it would turn a input of purchase dates against a specific CD, and then count them up and find the maximum number of purchases on a specific purchase_date.

For example turns this input:

```
CD_NO          purchasedate
1              2012-04-04
1              2012-04-04
1              2012-04-03
2              2012-04-03
2              2012-04-03
2              2012-04-03
2              2012-04-02
```

And turns it into:

```
CD_NO           most_sales
1               2012-04-04
2               2012-04-03
```

This is because it counts up the different dates for the CD_NO and then returns which date had the most.

Comment: Is this the 3rd time you ask this or even more?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CD_NO, COUNT(purchasedate) AS most_sales
INTO [NEW TABLE NAME] 
FROM Artist
GROUP BY CD_NO
```

ALL YOU hvae to do it put an into statement and the result will go to a new table on a basic level

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CD_NO, COUNT(purchasedate) AS most_sales
INTO ARTIST_SALES
FROM Artist
GROUP BY CD_NO
```

this should work,it will create a table called ARTIST_SALES ( you may change this), also you might consider adding the artist id in the second table, so you can select the summarized sales of each artist.

EDIT:

i didn't realize you were using mysql, select into is not supported, you should create a new table first, for example

```
CREATE TABLE Artist_Sales (
  CD_NO INT NOT NULL,
  SALES_COUNT INT NOT NULL
);
```

and then execute a insert into,
for example:

```
INSERT INTO Artis_Sales (CD_NO,SALES_COUNT)
SELECT CD_NO, COUNT(purchasedate) 
FROM Artist
GROUP BY CD_NO
```

good luck

Comment: When i try this it undeclared variable: Artist_Sales

Comment: ok, you are right, i didn't notice it was mysql, select into is not supported, so you should create a new table,

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just do this:

SELECT CD_NO, MAX(PURCHASEDATE) FROM ARTIST GROUP BY CD_NO

Comment: NO, and this just returns the most recent purchasedate